# 'spaceless' equivalent of Django templates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, django-templates, equivalent

Notice the readability and balance of:

```
<li class='aclass anotherclass <%= maybeaconditionalclass %>'>
   <a href="<%= some stuff %>">
     <%= some other stuff %>
   </a>
</li>
```

which unfortunately produces trailing whitespace inside the link resulting in a ugly trailing underline. Now although less readable I can live with this:

```
<li class='apossibleclass anotherclass <%= maybeaconditionalclass %>'>
   <a href="<%= some stuff %>"><%= some other stuff %></a>
</li>
```

Still, the same problem remains if I now consider this kind of thing:

```
li.apossibleclass:after {
    content: "/";
}
```

as the whitespace between the closing A and LI gets in the way of what should be sticking to my list item's end. I could only produce that ugly mess as a workaround:

```
<li class='apossibleclass anotherclass <%= maybeaconditionalclass %>'>
   <a href="<%= some stuff %>"><%= some other stuff %></a></li>
```

Django came up with a nice solution: [{% spaceless %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless), so I'm looking for the equivalent of the [{% spaceless %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless) tag in Rails erb templates.

Comment: Have you tried using the Rails helpers `link_to`, `content_tag` and `content_for`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that would be an useful feature, and as far as I know, there's nothing like it in Rails. So I've coded it.

```
# Strip all whitespace between the HTML tags in the passed block, and
# on its start and end.
def spaceless(&block)
  contents = capture(&block)

  # Note that string returned by +capture+ is implicitly HTML-safe,
  # and this mangling does not introduce unsafe changes, so I'm just
  # resetting the flag.
  contents.strip.gsub(/>\s+</, '><').html_safe
end
```

This is a helper you can place in your `application_helper.rb`, and then use like this:

```
<%= spaceless do %>
  <p>
      <a href="foo/"> Foo </a>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

... which will result in the output string like

```
<p><a href="foo/"> Foo </a></p>
```

Sadly, this only works in Rails 3. Rails 2 support for a feature like this will require some dirty hacks to ERb.

Comment: Looks very promising, I will try that as soon as I can.